# Wifi adapter is not showing up on mint

Tags: linux

I am new to Linux and I was working on some project. I change some file permission and my wifi adapter not working again.
Please help me.
Below is my log file.
[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMUmi.png)

Comment: My current permission 
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Mar 10 03:37 .
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root 4096 Mar 10 03:37 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2146 May 12  2016 01ifupdown
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 12  2016 no-wait.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 12  2016 pre-down.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 12  2016 pre-up.d

Comment: i tried to bring up the interface but receive this error ifup wlp2s0 
/etc/network/interfaces:6: unknown or no address type and no inherits keyword specified
ifdown: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"

Comment: Can you please try to run `chmod 775` to your files at `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`? Doesn't necessarily fix the whole problem, but it's a start.